# How To Make Dynamic Changing Upload Path

Tags: php

Im trying to make a file upload system where whenever a file is upload the file goes into a uploads folder set like this uploads/2012/09/{randomhash}/.

To do this i tried the code below.

```
$hash   = RandomString(20);
$upload_path = '../../uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$hash.'/';
if (!is_dir($upload_path))
{
    mkdir($upload_path, 0777);
}
```

For some reason its not working and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) has third parameter called `$recursive`. Set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Because apache (the user the mkdir() function tries to use when creating a directory) does not have the correct permissions on the directories you are attempting to change? This is my guess without more information from you.

Comment: I dont know what you mean but i have the uploads folder created already with permission of 777

Comment: I mean that you need to change the permissions of the directory you are trying to create a new directory in. If you (or the user apache, which is the username the web server is running on, assuming you're on linux with apache) do not have read/write permissions on the ../../upload/2012/09/29/ directory tree then you cannot make a new directory inside of it.